# Python can't find my custom module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I tried following this tutorial [The Instructions I Followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbPV7.png)

but I think I messed it up somehow (I am relatively new to python)

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tOFk.png) error when I try to import it. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it or what I did wrong. (I tried looking for help but they were all a bit confusing for me)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hyyj.png) is the contents of vigenere.py

Comment: What's the content of `vigenere.py`?

Comment: Sorry about that. https://i.imgur.com/rk4dn8w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the file/folder (`vigenere.py`) you are trying to import not is in you import path.

From within a python file, you can add path(s) incidentally to the default path by adding the following lines in the head section of your python application or script:

`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")`

Comment: I tried that with the path as "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\vigenere.py" and it still says it can't find it.

Comment: Thank you! That has made it work but if try to import it in another file without the sys.path.insert it doesn't work. Shouldn't that make it work throughout all the python files?

Comment: Everything is well explained [here](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html) - Easier with a link to a good article, than to explain everything here

Comment: That really helped. Sorry if it was stupid questions. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, we all have our challenges :)